# Loop through all elements with class 'blah' and find the highest id value

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of elements like:

```
<div id="car-123" class="blah">..</div>
```

I want to loop through all of them and get the highest ID i.e. 123

how to do this?

Is below correct and the best way?

```
$(".blah").each(function() {

   var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[0];

   if( id > newid)
      newid = id;

});
```

Comment: Are they written sequentially in the page by your server? Just grabbing the last would work in that case.

Comment: I think you mean `$(this)...[1]` not `[0]`

Comment: In addition to Gabi's comment, you need to wrap `$(this)...;` as `parseInt($(this)..., 10);` to do number comparison rather than string comparison (because "12" > "100").  Otherwise, this looks pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 17):

I would do:

```
var max = 0;
$(".blah").each(function(){
    num = parseInt(this.id.split("-")[1],10);
    if(num > max)
    {
       max = num;
    }
});
```

Most people would do this way.

Comment: instead of the `[1]` you could do `num = parseInt(this.id.split('-').pop(),10);`. Also might be a good idea to declare `var num;` at the same time as `var max = 0`

Answer (score 10):

I'd go for this, using `.map`, `.get` and `.sort`:

```
$('.blah').map(function(){
    return parseInt(this.id.split('-')[1], 10);
}).get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
})[0];
```

Comment: That is interesting...one thing I do like is that it doesn't introduce a local variable in to the scope.

Comment: The only thing i dont like is your using `parseInt`,`get`,`map`,`sort` where you can just use `each`,`parseInt`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `parseInt` so numerical operators apply

```
var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]);
```

Comment: That's almost the same as I have, but don't forget the radix parameter in `parseInt`: `parseInt( str, 10 );`

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the second value the splitted ID, and you might want to convert the string to an integer, like this:

```
var newid = 0;

$(".blah").each(function() {

  var id = parseInt( this.id.split('-')[1], 10 );

  if( id > newid)
    newid = id;

});
```