# How to target multiple instances of same <div> .class individually one at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I currently have x repeative setup of the same class:

```
<div class="span3">..content1</div>
<div class="span3">..content2</div>
<div class="span3">..content3</div>
```

How do I target each .span3 class individually without adding some unique id for each of them? Is that even possible?

What I want to do is apply some animation on each .span3 at a time with a little delay inbetween each - like fading one .span3 class up at a time or do some other animation like scale from 0 to 1.

Was trying to figure out if I could somehow add them to an array? And from there on id be able to iterate through the array doing whatever i wanted.

The .span class in more HTML context:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span3">
        <span>Headline</span>
        <img src="images/thumb_1.gif" class="img-polaroid">
      </div>
      <div class="span3 frameColor_yellow">
        <span>Headline</span>
        <img src="images/thumb_2.gif" class="img-polaroid">
      </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span3">
        <span>Headline</span>
        <img src="images/thumb_3.gif" class="img-polaroid">
      </div>
      <div class="span3 frameColor_yellow">
        <span>Headline</span>
        <img src="images/thumb_4.gif" class="img-polaroid">
      </div>
</div>
//etc...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is what you need http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: this was asked before [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619278/loop-through-all-elements-with-class-blah-and-find-the-highest-id-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this -

```
$('.span3').each(function(index,element){
    var sp = $(this);
    // do your stuff with this span
});
```

Comment: Just remember that many things are asynchronous so you might see them all happen at once despite doing this.

Comment: Thats exactly what im seeing. Just did a test fading up each span, and it seems to happen on all .span3 at a time? How would I go about this?

Comment: @user1231561 You can look at the answer below,,You can try that... i can't just copy them in my answer...http://stackoverflow.com/a/16201437/235710

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".row-fluid > .span3").each(function (index) {
    $(this).delay(index * 500).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mYMYX/1/)

Updated the answer based on @Rodrigo suggestion!

Comment: Great, also you can use `index * 500` instead of creating a `delay` variable

Comment: Thanks Palash Mondal - I used this in combination with Adils answer - works like a charm - thanks for taking the time for the fiddle also! truly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Proberbly you would like to wrap all your span3s inside a container, lets say

```
<div class="my-loop-divs">
   <div class="span3"></div>
   <div class="span3"></div>
</div>
```

I assume that you are using zepto or jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my-loop-divs .span3').each(function (index, element) {
        // do the animation on $(this)
    });
});
```